# format error when adding to AppDelegate.m

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am following react-native-codepush [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-ios.md) to add the following block to AppDelegate.m in React native 0.68.0/Xcode 13:

```
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  #if DEBUG
    return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #else
    return [CodePush bundleURL];
  #endif
}
```

Here is the AppDelegate.m after change:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h> /* for rn codepush */

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

/* for rn code push */
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  #if DEBUG
    return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #else
    return [CodePush bundleURL];
  #endif
}

@end
```

However there is error saying: `Expected ';' after method prototype`. I am not an expert on Xcode/IOS, what is really missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of method should not be included in **@interface ... end**, Only properties and methods are declared in **@interface ... end**

You are trying to write the definition of method in,

```
@interface 
...
@end
```

Instead add the method in

```
@implementation 
...
@end
```

So after adding your code, it should look like below,

```
@implementation 

/* for rn code push */
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  #if DEBUG
    return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #else
    return [CodePush bundleURL];
  #endif
}

@end
```

Comment: `Gangadhar Gandi`, many thanks. Do I need method definition after @implementation AppDelegate: ...? The Xcode says `Use of undeclared identifier 'RCTBundleURLProvider'`. I am completely new with object-c.